# Javascript element id to AJAX url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'd like to make a form containing a couple of input fields. While typing something in these fields, a dropdown has to appear containing the matching records from a MySQL database. Following is the Javascript-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#sampleprep, #quantity, #sampletype, #organism").autocomplete({
            response: function(event, ui) {
                try {
                    // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
                    if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                        $("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").text("No results found");
                    } else {
                        $("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").empty();
                        //$("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").text(event.target.id);
                    }
                } catch(err) {
                    error = "Error 1: "+err.message;
                    alert(error);
                }
            },

            source: function(request, response) {
                try {
                    var target_id = "sampletype";            <====

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "list_"+target_id+".php",       <====
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            term : request.term
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                } catch(err) {
                    error = "Error 2: "+err.message;
                    alert(error);
                }
            },
            minlength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, there are 4 input fields using this code:

- sampleprep
- quantity
- sampletype
- organism

Each input field corresponds to it's own database table. I made 4 PHP-files to get the matching data. Filenames are:

- list_sampleprep.php
- list_quantity.php
- list_sampletype.php
- list_organism.php

My problem is indicated by the arrow `<====`. Right now, the url is fixed to `list_sampletype.php`. I'd like to make this dynamic, but I can't figure out how to get the id of the inputfield into the ajax-call. I tried `event.target.id`, which is working in the first function, as well as some other things, but nothing returned what I want.

Comment: It will be better if u write 4 different autocomplete methods for 4 different fields

Comment: Is there really no way to get the id? The only thing that's different each time is the url. I want to keep my code tidy if possible, without spamming the same number of lines over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".ajax_getid_").each(function () {
            (function ($this) {
                $this.autocomplete({
                response: function(event, ui) {
                    try {
                        // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
                    if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                        $("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").text("No results found");
                    } else {
                        $("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").empty();
                        //$("#"+event.target.id+"-empty-message").text(event.target.id);
                    }
                        } catch(err) {
                            error = "Error 1: "+err.message;
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    },

                    source: function(request, response) {
                        try {
                            var target_id = "sampletype";            <====

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "list_"+$this.attr('id')+".php",       <====
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    term : request.term
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch(err) {
                            error = "Error 2: "+err.message;
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    },
                    minlength: 1
                });
            })($(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```

In order to explained : For each element, you will execute the same function and you will use the ID of the element selected.

Comment: That doesn't do anything. I don't even get the dropdown anymore

Comment: @Fingashpitzzz can you add a class to your id called "ajax_getid_" and replace `$("#sampleprep, #quantity, #sampletype, #organism")` by `$(".ajax_getid_")`. it will work

Comment: That returns the result of the last script (list_organism.php) for all of the fields, not the corresponding script for each field

Comment: Jep, I did. And my input-fields are coded like this: `<input class = "ajax_getid_" id = "organism" name = "organism" type = "text" style = "width: 200px" placeholder = "Used organism">` with only id's and names different each time

Comment: Just to clarify, the organism input-field is the last one in the form, and all four input-fields are returning the organism-values

Comment: It's because you have to create a context because of an asynchonous action due to the ajax initialization. Please, retry my new code. @Fingashpitzzz

Comment: Sorry for my late response, had a more urgent task to do... Your latest code works for me now! Couldn't have done it alone (my very first attempt to javascript), so thanks for your patience and help!